# how to save text file in to sql server database using php

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I am creating text file in my PHP website.

I want to save the text file into the sql server 2008 database.

The database type is IMAGE type.

How can i save my text file into the sql server database's IMAGE data type field ?

Can anyone please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

The following php functions may help get you started for what you're looking for:

- [`imagecreatefrompng`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php)
- [`imagepng`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php)

And here are all of the php [Image functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php).